# findAll method of DataService class returns only 100 entities

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

We've successfully migrated our v2 QBO to v3 and after that on the production we got an issue from one of our customers. They have over 100 their customers in QBO account. And they want to copy them into our application. We implemented an import like this:

```
    DataService service = getDataService(owner);  // obtain DataService via Access Keys
    List<com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer> customers = 
         service.findAll(new com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer()); 
    for (com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer customer : customers) {
        createCustomer(customer, owner);  // this is our internal method to create
    }
```

As mentioned in [Class Library Reference](http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/ipp-v3-java-devkit-javadoc/) - method findAll is a

```
    Method to retrieve all records for the given entity.
```

But our customer is getting **only first 100 entities** (Customer's) from his QBO v3 account. And if he do the same import operation - he will get the same first 100 entities again. This method doesn't allow any pagination options.

So the question is, how to get **all** of the entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Query endpoint with page filters.

The following query gets customers 1 - 10:

```
String query = select($(customer)).skip(0).take(10).generate();
```

Output - `SELECT * FROM Customer STARTPOSITION 1 MAXRESULTS 10`

The following query gets customers 21 - 25:

```
String query = select($(customer)).skip(20).take(10).generate();
```

Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0201_ipp_java_devkit_3.0/0011_query_filters#Pagination

finally

```
QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery(query);
```

Thanks

Comment: Manas, did you see the question? We do not need the pagination. We need to get **all** of the entities? The method provided in API doesn't do so. So we have to use Query API then?

Comment: Did you refer the docs ? If not , please refer - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00300_query_operations#Maximum_Number_of_Entities_in_a_Response
. There is nothing like GetAll endpoint in V3. GetAll is just a wrapper on top of query endpoint(query - select * from Customer). 
Bydefault it returns 100 objects. Thanks

Comment: The query from reference gives the following error
`Error ERROR CODE:4001, ERROR MESSAGE:Invalid query, ERROR DETAIL:QueryValidationError: Property Status not found for Entity Customer`
Even if I remove the status where clause - Invalid query error appears. We combine the query like shown in the reference:
`com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer _customer = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer.class);
            QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery(select($(_customer)).where($(_customer.getStatus()).eq(EntityStatusEnum.SYNCHRONIZED)).generate());`

Comment: `select($(_customer)).take(150).generate()` - generates the following query: `SELECT tring.* FROM Customer MAXRESULTS 150` - which gives an error  `QueryValidationError: Property tring not found for Entity Customer`.

Comment: What is 'tring.*' in your query ?

Comment: 'status' was part of deprecated V3 QBD(customer) endpoints. In QBO that field is not present. Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/030_entity_services_reference/customer

You can simply ignore the status field in the queryBuilder and use only the required part related to pagination. I've update my post with an ex.

Comment: I do not know what is 'tring'. I just use the static 'select' and '$' methods of provided functionality. And method 'generate()' returns the query with this 'tring' inside. Maybe there were some version changes/updates of QBO v3 API?

Comment: I'm sorry, that is working now, thank you. Maybe something was wrong in our build or else.

Answer (score 2):

To fetch all of customers for a specified business, first you need to get their count, and then, as mentioned at the previous answer, get the customers by "take" method:

```
        Integer customersTotal = service.executeQuery(selectCount(_customer).generate()).getTotalCount();
        QueryResult queryResult = service.executeQuery(select($(_customer)).skip(0).take(customersTotal).generate());
        List<? extends IEntity> entities = queryResult.getEntities();
        for (IEntity entity : entities) {
            if (entity instanceof com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer) {
                createCustomer((com.intuit.ipp.data.Customer) entity, owner);
            }
        }
```