# DataService.findAll is returning only 100 records

Tags: java, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I have successfully connect my app to intuit quick books but when I am calling 
dataService.findAll(new Account()) it is only loading 100 records , but I need to increase the result size .

```
    Context context = getIntuitPlatformContext(user);
    DataService dataService = new DataService(context);
    return dataService.findAll(new Account());
```

Comment: have you tried this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909923/findall-method-of-dataservice-class-returns-only-100-entities

Comment: Duplicate, vote to close.